# Displaying validation results properly in Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

My Question is little complicated, But experts may understand what i am trying to ask.

I have the following code in Jquery which submits a form and display the validation result from the destination page.

```
submitHandler : function(form) {
if($('#login').submit(function(){return false;}))
{
$.ajax
({
type: 'POST',
url: $('#login').attr('action'),
data: $('#login').serialize(),
success: function(data) 
{
$('#results').html(data);
}
});
}
return false;
},
```

The destination page is in php.
The content displayed in #results is php processed validation results

**My Issue is -** 
Iam getting some alpha numeric strings with the validation result as follows

**{"output":"","status":-1,"error_messages":{"error":["please enter your name."],"success":[]}}**

This is because i have a php file called message.php this validation results should be come through  message.php. it is exaclty processing and stripping the unwanted charectors and displays the error message properly.

Is there any way to do this in the above JavaScript(Jquery)that the the validation results should come through message.php instead of direct displaying to avoid putting unwanted characters in validation results (only validation result should be displayed)..

Or any other suggestions you have ?

Looking forward for a favorable action from an expert..

Regards
TOM

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**
When turning off the browsers **JavaScript** the result is producing correctly, because the form is not submitting through jquery-Ajax (through form action="") and validation messages come through messages.php.

The messages are displaying as

```
<?php 
 echo $messages; 
 ?>
```

Comment: Hm; Is it "message.php is only executed if javascript is disabled, but not if you do the ajax call" what you arr saying? Please add some more information. What is the action at the form, is the #login the form or something else with a different action?

Comment: That is not a subject in this issue .where the form is sending to (action).. Iam talking about the results producing after the form has been sent successfully.. Please read and reply..

Comment: Well: Than I do not understand what your "ADDITIONAL INFORMATION" should tell us.

Comment: That refers the validations messages comes through messages.php if it is not submitting through Ajax..Please Read what i have stated before the Additional information. IF YOU DONT; UNDERSTAND LEAVE THE MATTER...PLEASE!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm ignoring `data['output']` and `data['status']` because i don't really know how you plan to use them and what values they could have.  I'll assume that the success or error message returned is sufficient for the user.

It looks like `data` contains JSON so why not pull out the relevant success or error message?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/xjJP2/)**

```
...
success: function(data)   
{
    var msg = data['error_messages']['success'][0] != '' ?  data['error_messages']['success'][0] : data['error_messages']['error'][0] ; 
   $('#results').html( msg );
}
...
```

Comment: @gillyspy.. Thanks..the error iam getting is  "error_messages.sucess is null or not an object" .. Any additional information needed ?

Comment: @gillyspy.. could u pls explain the method you are using ?

Comment: you gave us an example of your results.  It seems that you have an interest in only displaying results that are relevant to the end-user in a way they can understand.  You didn't specify if you want to display success and / or failure so i'm displaying either in the `$('#results')` element.  I'll write a fiddle for you.

Comment: Thank you.. I am trying to display both success and failure error messages.. i mean..

Comment: Thanks.. Is the fiddle is preparing a fake validation message in javascript ? It is not displaying the error message or validation message from action page in php?

Comment: it is not able to truly call out to a php page so it calls out to `/echo/json` and the fake response is provided by `fakeValuesToSubmit`.  But you can see that the response is correct by looking at `console.log("done!",data);` or make it `console.log("done!",JSON.stringify(data))` if you prefer

Comment: Thanks.. Stripping out the unwanted outputs by using slice() is professional ?

Comment: what `slice()` are you referring to? What are the unwanted outputs? You have never stated what they are clearly.

Comment: my output is already stated in the question as follows. {"output":"","status":-1,"error_messages":{"error":["please enter your name."],"success":[]}} javscript.slice(5, -3);

Comment: I'm confused, the word `slice` only appears on this page in these comments and not in the question nor the fiddle.  Either way, I would never use slice to manipulate a json string / data.

Or perhaps you're asking if it is best-practice to perform a slice on the error/success string?  I would say, in general, no.  it would be fine for a test, or a band-aid, but if the error you are generating is not user-friendly enough then you should have a user-friendly version that is generated on the server-side, or a "translation" component that can handle your error strings and change them.

Comment: Thank you for making a fiddle for helping me..Exactly the fiddle is completely not getting for me.. It will not produce the error result "please enter a name" which is in php validation code ? instead of that("please enter a name") we produce a fake result in javscript?

Comment: Additionally the stuff we are using is browser compatible ?, but slice is fully compatible with all browsers i mean.. But if you say using slice in this subject is unethical, i want to come with you..

Comment: in the fiddle -- if you enter a blank name and hit enter it will complain with "please enter a name".  define "all browsers". You have to draw a line somewhere, where do you draw your line? Implicitly you have made a choice of browsers that are supported by jquery, is there something different you want to support?  something narrower?

Answer (score 0):

The answer form @gillyspy is right.
the only part missing is to parts the ajax return data string as jason.

Either add `dataType: 'json',`to your ajax request.
  Or change your success function to

```
success: function(str) 
            {
                var data =$.parseJSON(str);
                var msg = data['error_messages']['success'].length != 0 ?  data['error_messages']['success'][0] : data['error_messages']['error'][0] ; 
                $('#results').html( msg );
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for spending your valuable time.. But iam not getting correct output while using the above code... Could u please check ...